# Diesel car is surging

Tags: diesel, peugeot, surging, peugeot-307

[Video of how it behaves during constant speed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RW4Cd.jpg).

The car is a 2007 PEUGEOT 307 T6 2.0L Turbo Diesel Direct Inj. 4cyl 100kW HDi Auto. This has just started happening, and seems to be more pronounced at lower speeds. What are the likely causes of this?  Is there a way I can do any tests to find out more info without spending money at a mechanic?  Eg. a diagnostic tool?

Comment: Can you hear the engine surging?

Comment: Does it surge in neutral, at idle? The cheapest diagnostic tool out there is a bluetooth OBD reader paired with a free app on a phone or tablet like Torque, you can read diagnostic codes, there may be an answer there. Some auto parts stores in the states will read your codes for free, not sure if they do that where you are.

Comment: @HandyHowie yes, and can feel it when driving - it's very noticeable at lower speeds.

Comment: @GdD No, it doesn't seem to. I've seen a lot of YouTube videos about fixes for the idle surge, but not much at all for surge under power (especially at low speeds). And thanks for the advice about the OBD reader.